# как банить по id? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, discord, discord.py

если нужно просто забанить 1 id, то можно вместо `line` указать id, но мне нужно забанить все id которые находяться в файле

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    f = open("fban", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        user = bot.get_user(line)
        await ctx.guild.ban(user)
```

получаю ошибку:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: В указанной вами ошибке написано, что объект типа `None` не имеет свойства `send`, однако в приложенном коде вообще нет слова "`send`". А так, если id написаны каждый в отдельной строчке без опечаток и лишних символов, то все должно работать. Если у вас не включены [**намерения**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), то вместо `get_user()` можете воспользоваться `user = await bot.fetch_user()`

Comment: ах да, вообщем это был тестовый код, и я ошибку с тестового кода взял, а сам код с настоящего проекта, щас заменю ошибку

Comment: прислушался к вашему совету, и вместо `user = bot.get_user(line)` поставил `user = await bot.fetch_user()`, и код заработал, спасибо вам большое